# How to tell when nothing selected in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have a ComboBox which is being populated by a LINQ query:

```
var locations = 
    from loc in db.LOCATIONs
        .Where(a => a.Omit == false)
select new
{
    LocationID = loc.LocationID,
    Location = loc.Location1
};

cbo = this.cboAdminLocation;
cbo.DataSource = locations;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Location";
cbo.ValueMember = "LocationID";
cbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

I also have a routine DisplayAccounts() which lists all accounts in a DataGridView, but filtered by the value selected in the combo, if selected, or displays all accounts if not. I thought this would be quite simple, and am trying to handle it with the following statements within DisplayAccounts():

```
if (this.cboAdminLocation.SelectedIndex > -1)
    filterAdminLocation = Convert.ToInt32(this.cboAdminLocation.SelectedValue.ToString());
else
    filterAdminLocation = 0;
```

and at the end of the LINQ query:

```
if (filterAdminLocation > 0)
{
    accountData = accountData.Where(a => a.LocationID == filterAdminLocation);
}
```

However, I am getting an error on the first loop round (i.e. before having a chance to select a value from the Combo) of "Input string was not in the correct format.", and indeed the value of the combo at this stage is displayed as `{ LocationID = 1, Location = "Brentwood" }` and the selected index is 0. If I skip over this step and test when I have selected a value it returns an integer value as expected.

Therefore, my question is why does get past the `if (this.cboAdminLocation.SelectedIndex > -1)` test when the selected index is supposedly 0, and more to the point why is the selected index 0 when I explicitly set it to -1 when populating the control?

I appreciate this is probably very simple, but I'm fairly new to C# so you'll have to excuse my stupidity!

Comment: I usually curcumvent the issue initializing the collection i bind to the comboboxes with a dummy item which stands for "nothing is selected". Then, I append my items, and bind it. Works smoothly, without having to nullcheck the selection anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore, my question is why does get past the if (this.cboAdminLocation.SelectedIndex > -1) test when the selected index is supposedly 0, and more to the point why is the selected index 0 when I explicitly set it to -1 when populating the control?

This is because you *first* populate the comboBox, *then* set the selected index to `-1`. Between this two steps, the selected index is - for a short time - `0`.

In order to correct that, you could call your `DisplayAccounts()` routine only after you've run `cbo.SelectedIndex = -1;`. I guess you call `DisplayAccounts()` in the comboBox' SelectedIndexChanged event. If so, attach the event to the comboBox after it (and be sure to remove it from the *Designer.cs* file if you've added the event in the Designer window):

```
//...
cbo = this.cboAdminLocation;
cbo.DataSource = locations;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Location";
cbo.ValueMember = "LocationID";
cbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
cbo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cbo_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Does not explain the exception on the first pass.  Process 0 was needles but why does it fail?  Suspect it does not yet know ValueMember so it is passing string Location which is consistent with the error message.  I think you can Set the DisplayMember and ValueMember before the DataSource.   The solution you posted does have the benefit of not processing 0 but I am still curious as to why 0 would fail.